# Numeric differentiation of PDF

Tags: statistics, derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am new to numeric differentiation. How might I go about approximating the value of a derivative $\partial y/\partial x$ at a particular $x$?

$y = \log(f_X(x))$

$f_X$ is a probability density function defined over $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: Are you able to compute $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{X}^{\prime}(x)$ easily (do you have analytic expressions)?

Comment: $f_X$ has an analytic expression, but it may be difficult to find one for $f'_X$

Comment: If you want to compute $dy/dx$ numerically and have an expression for $f_X$, then I'd suggest looking into automatic(algorithmic)-differentiation tools. Julia's `ForwardDiff` is one example: https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl, though note that this is different from finite-differencing and gives a (numerically) "exact" derivative